# Passing variadic template function arguments to another function

Tags: c++

Straight up, there was a similar question, but different at its core.

So, here is what I'm trying to do - lets say I have a variadic template function which takes `T ...args` and a function type `FuncT funcName`, so here is what we have so far:

```cpp
template<typename FuncT, typename ...T>
void myFunction(FuncT (*funcName), T ...args);
```

Now, I want to store my function at `void (*)()` (this store functions). This works just fine.

Now, I can just pass a function to my function as in:

```cpp
template<typename FuncT, typename T>
void myFunction(FuncT (*funcName), T singleArgument){
  funcName(T singleArgument);
}

void function(int i){
  std::cout << i;
}

int main(){
  myFunction(function, 5);
}
```

Ok, we successfully passed a single argument, but the function I pass to `myFunction()` **accepts variable amount of argument**. What if I pass `function2(int a, int b)` and not just `function(int a)`? **Well, here is where my question comes in**.

When I use:

```cpp
template<typename FuncT, typename T>
void myFunction(FuncT (*funcName), T singleArgument){
  funcName(/* What should i write here */);
}

void function1(int a){
  std::cout << a;
}

void function2(int a, int b){
  std::cout << a << " " << b;
}

int main(){
  myFunction(function1, 42);
  myFunction(function2, 42, 0);
}
```

Then I `args`, which I could pass to the function that accepts `variadic template arguments`, but my function accepts just some fixed amount of `int`, `char` and other.

Comment: Step 1 would usually be to check [the documentation on varargs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic). Step 2 would be to write a function with `...` in it. Note that these are a *lot* harder to work with than varidic template args.

Comment: Please share a link to the "similar question". It's always nice to show relevant context when possible.

Comment: Huh. Never occurred to me that you can use `FuncT (*)` to deduce function pointers like that; I've always just specified the full type of `R(*)(Args...)` -- but this makes sense for deduction rules.

Comment: @Human-Compiler The brackets doesn't do anything here. You can remove them and get the same. It's just accepting any pointer. `FuncT* funcName`.

Comment: @super Ah, thank you for clarifying that -- that makes much more sense to me. I was thinking this was some special syntax I hadn't seen that ensures function pointers (kind of like how a member pointer can deduce abominable types for member function pointers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use perfect forwarding:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename FuncType, typename... Args>
void myFunction(FuncType funcName, Args&&... args){
  funcName(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void function1(int a){
  std::cout << a;
}

void function2(int a, int b){
  std::cout << a << " " << b;
}

int main(){
  myFunction(function1, 42);
  myFunction(function2, 42, 0);
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a715dc67a30c4ce5